# Reading CSV Files with Java (SE8)

Tags: java, csv

I want to use the following code to extract data from a dataset within a csv file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingCSVFiles {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File dataFile = new File("URL\Countries.csv");
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(dataFile);
        input.useDelimiter(",|\\s");
        String column1 = input.next();
        String column2 = input.next();
        System.out.printf("%-11s%12s%n", column1, column2);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String Country = input.next();
            int Population = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%-11s%, 12d%n", Country, Population);
            }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get the first line as output:

```
Country           Population
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor (Unknown Source)
    at ...
```

Here is the csv.file:

```
Country,Population
Argentina,41343201
Brazil,201103330
Chile,16746491
Columbia,47790000
Paraguay,6375830
Peru,29907003
Venezuela,27223228
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first line is of format String,String, not String,Number. Could that be your basic issue?

Comment: I have run the code with your example and there was no exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You set your delimiter to `,` or `\s`, which matches only one white space character.

If your file endings are delimited by two characters (as is default on Windows systems), e.g. `\r\n`, it will only consume the first character (`\r`), meaning the next token will be an empty String (read into `Country`), and the token after that will be the next country name, which cannot be read as an int.

I'd suggest reading your input line by line and then split those lines using `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). If it's for didactic purposes then I think you need another call to `next()`

Answer (score 0):

It was almost correct.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingCSVFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dataFile = new File("URL\\Countries.csv");
        // the resources MUST be closed! Do not suppress these kind of warnings!
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(dataFile)) {
            // what you forget is the newline: at the end of the lines, there maybe more than one white space character (on windows,\r\n)
            input.useDelimiter(",|\\s+");
            String column1 = input.next();
            String column2 = input.next();
            System.out.printf("columns: %-11s%12s%n", column1, column2);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String Country = input.next();
                int Population = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%-11s%, 12d%n", Country, Population);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the diff?

Comment: The most important diff was the + sign in useDelimiter: "input.useDelimiter(",|\\s+");", another thing is the try-with-resources statement in order to definitely close the scanner at the end of processing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use opencsv lib http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ , just create a DTO like

```
 public class CountryAndPopulationDTO implements Serializable{

 private String country ;
 private String population;

 // getter & setter 
 }

// in your main

FileReader filereader = new FileReader(dataFile);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(filereader, ',');
Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

columnMapping.put("country", "country");
columnMapping.put("population", "population");

HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<CountryAndPopulationDTO> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<CountryAndPopulationDTO>();
strategy.setType(CountryAndPopulationDTO.class);
strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);
List<CountryAndPopulationDTO> countryAndPopulationDTOList= new ArrayList<CountryAndPopulationDTO>();
try {
CsvToBean<CountryAndPopulationDTO> csv = new CsvToBean<CountryAndPopulationDTO>() {
    protected Object convertValue(String value, PropertyDescriptor prop) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            value = null;
        }
        return super.convertValue(value, prop);
    }
};
log.info(" -----------------  MAPPING CSV FILE  ----------------------------");
countryAndPopulationDTOList = csv.parse(strategy, reader); 

}catch (Exception e) {
 throw new Exception("Mapping problem --> ", e.getCause());
}
```

// Now countryAndPopulationDTOList  has all your data :)

Comment: Commons CSV can be used too.

Comment: univocity-parsers beats them all and is 3 times faster.